# Make internet app available only within VPN?

Tags: networking, server, internet, vpn, services

I am not sure if I expressed myself clear enough in the question.

Just managed to set up PPTP on my server and I want to know how can I make a website be accessible only from VPN clients. I have apache and other services installed and I can host a website and access it from all over the world. But I want a specific one like: www.therestrictedone.com to be accessible only by VPN clients.

Is this possible?

Can I make apache work simultaneously on two ports. So port 80 is accessible from Internet and 81 only within VPN?

Probably I am saying lot of things without sense? I am just trying to express whats going through my mind with my own words.

Answer (score 0):

Couple different ways to do this. If you have no intentions of hosting any other site except for vpn access the quickest and easiest way would be to use a firewall and only allow from local network. Anyone that connects to vpn will be given a local address such as 192.168.1.x. So using UFW

```
 sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
```

If you intend to have other sites and are setting this up as a vhost, usually you can throw in an

```
 Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

Or

```
 Allow from 192.168.1.*
```

In the vhost configuration. I forget the exact format for ip range, but it one of the two referenced above. Just look up info on Apache vhosts